# Sony Emma FlashTool saying Unable to connect to the network and exits suddenly while I have network

Tags: rom-flashing, sony-xperia, flashtool

When I'm running sony flash tool (Emma) it shows me following error and suddenly exits:

> Unable to connect to the network, please check your network connection.

[image]

But I have a connected internet and checked firewall not blocking emma. Why showing this error? I need this tormentor emma flash tool to install an official stock rom in FTF format. On my experience emma flash tool is very weak in design and stops woking with strange and non-described error messages. Are there any alternatives to do same thing without any kind of torturing? Previously, I used odin for my other Samsung smartphone and it was doing its jobs much better.

Answer (score -1):

try updating your JAVA. It might work...
If you Want to fash a new Rom, 'Flashtool for sony' will be very useful. It is very easy to Use.